# How do I count the number of processors on an OpenBSD system?

Tags: openbsd, central-processing-unit

How can I determine the number of CPUs on an OpenBSD system, using either system tools or C code?

The technique I know of to count CPUs on other BSD platforms -- checking `/var/run/dmesg.boot` for certain strings, doesn't always seem to work.

**More context:** Unfortunately, I don't have an OpenBSD system available to play around with. I am trying to address [the OpenBSD-specific test failures](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Sys-CpuAffinity+0.98) for a Perl module.

Comment: Also, you might like http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On OpenBSD you have:

```
sysctl hw.ncpu
```

or

```
sysctl hw.ncpufound
```

As explained in [sysctl(3)](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-4.8/sysctl.3), ncpu is the number of CPU used by system and ncpufound is the number of CPU found by the system.

By the way, [devio.us](http://devio.us/) provides free shell account on OpenBSD servers.

Comment: Thanks for the great tip about `devio.us`! That will make it easier to answer all my other OpenBSD questions.

Answer (score 4):

On FreeBSD, it's

```
sysctl -n hw.ncpu
```

and on Darwin

```
sysctl -n hw.availcpu
```

So perhaps it's similar?  There is a system call, I think, but I'd poke around with the command line first.

Answer (score 2):

The internet tells me to try this

```
dmesg | grep -i CPU
```

or

```
sysctl -a | egrep -i 'hw.machine|hw.model|hw.ncpu'
```

is cpuinfo available?? I know you can have it on BSD variants..

Answer (score 1):

In 6.4 `ncpuonline` was added and as of 7.0 [`sysctl(2)`](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-7.0/sysctl.2) states:

> [HW_NCPU](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-7.0/sysctl.2#HW_NCPU%7E2) (*hw.ncpu*) 
>     The number of CPUs configured. 
> [HW_NCPUFOUND](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-7.0/sysctl.2#HW_NCPUFOUND%7E2) (*hw.ncpufound*) 
>     The number of CPUs found. 
> [HW_NCPUONLINE](https://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-7.0/sysctl.2#HW_NCPUONLINE%7E2) (*hw.ncpuonline*) 
>     The number of CPUs online.

Further information on `ncpuonline` is available in revision ([openbsd-cvs](https://marc.info/?l=openbsd-cvs&w=2&r=1&s=ncpuonline&q=b)).